# Android Expanding a single ListView Item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, expand

i have a list view with 3 buttons it. the functionality of those button would be that when clicked that single view should expand in height to show a text box. i havent done any code in the CustomAdapter of that listview to provide any reference to it.

Comment: what exactly do you need ? What problem do you wish to get solved ?

Comment: i want to achieve something similar to this but with a button click which is placed inside each cell of the listview

http://udinic.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/expanding-listview-items/

Answer (score 0):

What you just described is an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

**EDIT**: Also, you can have the TextView's visibility set to "gone" and just become visible when the button is clicked.

Comment: Ohkay with expandable list view. But wont it seperate the parent and child view (child view is the view which will be diaplayed on button click)

Comment: Seperate? No. The child view will be displayed directly underneath the parent. [This seems to be a good example](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/). There's a bit of extra work with ExpandableListViews, though.

Comment: What if i dont want an extra view ... What i want is that the view gets expanded persisting the background image. The view should have a slide dpwn type animation and show the item hiding beneath.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for then. ExpandableListView does what your question asks; you can customize the child view to look like whatever you want. Any specific animations you want it to have would need further investigation (and another question) on your part.